# Dimensionality reduction and numerical regression analysis with complex numbers as the response

Tags: python, scikit-learn, neural-network, dimensionality-reduction

I have a dataset containing magnitude and phase from some analysis as the response, these responses(200 responses) are in  **COMPLEX NUMBERS**

since the data set contains large number of input parameters( the input parameters are same for all reposnes), I want use **[selectkbest](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjkrPOUrsfrAhW873MBHfXKB58QFjAAegQIAxAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fscikit-learn.org%2Fstable%2Fmodules%2Fgenerated%2Fsklearn.feature_selection.SelectKBest.html&usg=AOvVaw2l-6VTQou3ZzyEOUBhnK4e2l-6VTQou3ZzyEOUBhnK4e)** method to reduce the dimension, but **[selectkbest](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjkrPOUrsfrAhW873MBHfXKB58QFjAAegQIAxAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fscikit-learn.org%2Fstable%2Fmodules%2Fgenerated%2Fsklearn.feature_selection.SelectKBest.html&usg=AOvVaw2l-6VTQou3ZzyEOUBhnK4e2l-6VTQou3ZzyEOUBhnK4e)**, doesn't support complex data
so,

Question 1:

Is there any method to reduce the dimension in similar way selecktkbest does, which can take in **COMPLEX NUMBERS** as the respsonse?

Question 2:

Is there a possibility to do numerical regression analysis in neural network with **complex numbers** as the response?

error  :

````
<ipython-input-11-3df44143e2f3> in <module>
      2 Y = responses
      3 best_features = SelectKBest(score_func=f_regression, k=50)
----> 4 fit = best_features.fit(X,Y)
      5 df_scores = pd.DataFrame(fit.scores_)
      6 df_columns = pd.DataFrame(X.columns)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_selection\_univariate_selection.py in fit(self, X, y)
    339         self : object
    340         """
--> 341         X, y = check_X_y(X, y, ['csr', 'csc'], multi_output=True)
    342 
    343         if not callable(self.score_func):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_X_y(X, y, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, multi_output, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, y_numeric, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    756     if multi_output:
    757         y = check_array(y, 'csr', force_all_finite=True, ensure_2d=False,
--> 758                         dtype=None)
    759     else:
    760         y = column_or_1d(y, warn=True)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    538         # result is that np.array(..) produces an array of complex dtype
    539         # and we need to catch and raise exception for such cases.
--> 540         _ensure_no_complex_data(array)
    541 
    542         if ensure_2d:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in _ensure_no_complex_data(array)
    345             and hasattr(array.dtype, 'kind') and array.dtype.kind == "c":
    346         raise ValueError("Complex data not supported\n"
--> 347                          "{}\n".format(array))
    348 
    349 

ValueError: Complex data not supported
[21.+175.j 98.+198.j 28.+130.j ... 83.+146.j 57.+187.j 95.+191.j]```
````

Comment: Previously I performed NN classification over GNSS signals but I studied the phase and amplitude apart not together. I think you need to split them and perform regression on each variable apart

Comment: Thank you for the response, yes we can split them and take separately, but here I need them as a single response(amplitude and phase(complex number))which accelerates my process since there are huge number of responses.